# PostgreSQL subquery split rows (error is more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression)

Tags: postgresql

this is my first post on stackoverflow so please be gentle.  I have researched this problem and came up with many varied solutions...all of which seem to be just off from what I need.  I have a postgresql subquery in a SELECT statement that returns multiple rows, which I know is obviously not ideal/allowed/sensible/etc....   However, this is the case for my current problem and I need to be able to take those multiple returned rows and apply them to every previous corresponding record row that they originally came out of.

## Current Query:

```
SELECT cohead_number "Sales Order#",
       cohead_custponumber "Purchase Order#",
       item_number "Part Number",
       item_descrip1 "Part Description",
       CAST(shipitem_qty AS integer) "Item Quantity",
       getPacklistItemLotSerial(shiphead_id, coitem_id) AS "LotNumbers"  --this is the duplicating row subquery that I need listed in separate rows without changing other respective columns--
FROM   cohead
       LEFT JOIN coitem
              ON coitem_cohead_id = cohead_id
       LEFT JOIN shipitem
              ON coitem_id = shipitem_orderitem_id
       LEFT JOIN itemsite
              ON coitem_itemsite_id = itemsite_id
       LEFT JOIN item
              ON itemsite_item_id = item_id
       LEFT JOIN shiphead
              ON shiphead_order_id = cohead_id
WHERE cohead_number = '79464' --this is just to test with one sales order instead of all (sales order being the input for the query)--
```

## Results:

[LINK: Results of above query here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWNGf.png)

## What I Have Tried

Now, this line lets me split the column results via the delimiter ',' but I can't figure out how to get the results from this back into my original query's results:

```
(SELECT lot from regexp_split_to_table(getPacklistItemLotSerial(shiphead_id, coitem_id),', ') AS lot)
```

## Results:

Here I input the shiphead_id and coitem_id for the example sales order so it can show you the resulting split column into rows.

> SELECT lot from regexp_split_to_table(getPacklistItemLotSerial(22082, 50351),', ') AS lot

[LINK: Results of Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qikvx.png)

Please help walk me through what I need to do to achieve this.  I imaging we need to declare some things and maybe join 2 tables in a more complex query...I don't really know.  Thank you for any help you can offer.

## *EDIT*

Added in the requested source code for the Function "getpacklistitemlotserial"

```
DECLARE
  pShipheadId ALIAS FOR $1;
  pOrderItemId ALIAS FOR $2;
  _lotserial text;
  _r RECORD;
  _first BOOLEAN;

BEGIN

  --Test to see if Lot/Serial Enabled
  SELECT metric_value INTO _lotserial
  FROM metric
  WHERE ((metric_name='LotSerialControl')
  AND (metric_value ='t'));

  IF (FOUND) THEN
    _lotserial := '';
    _first := true;

    FOR _r IN SELECT DISTINCT ls_number
              FROM invdetail, invhist, shipitem, ls
             WHERE ((shipitem_shiphead_id=pShipheadId)
               AND  (shipitem_orderitem_id=pOrderItemId)
               AND  (shipitem_invhist_id=invhist_id)
               AND  (invhist_id=invdetail_invhist_id)
               AND  (invdetail_ls_id=ls_id)) LOOP
      IF (_first = false) THEN
        _lotserial := _lotserial || ', ';
      END IF;
      _lotserial := _lotserial || _r.ls_number;
      _first := false;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN _lotserial;
  ELSE
    RETURN '';
  END IF;

END
```

Comment: It seems that `getPacklistItemLotSerial` function does some kind of aggregation and it returns multiple values combined into a comma  separated list. What you want is to split back that list into indyvidual values. The question is - why don't discard that function completely and include it's implementation directly into the query ? You can save a lot of overhead, I bet that this can be even 30-50 times faster (yes - 50 times = 5000%). Could you append a source code of this function to the question ?

Comment: Edited my original post and added the code for that function after "Edit".   I am open to ideas on how to make this query more efficient and there are no restrictions really for what I can and can't do as long as the code works.  Thanks for the quick response and help!

Comment: One more question - a call to the function contains two parameters (column names) -`getPacklistItemLotSerial(shiphead_id, coitem_id)`. Since any of column names in the query don't have column prefixes, it is hard to guess which one comes from which table. Could you explan which column does come from which table ? I suppose that `coitem_id` comes from `coitem` table, buf can't guess what table does `shiphead_id` column come from ?

Comment: Gotcha, the shiphead_id comes from the table shiphead.  The coitem_id does come from coitem table as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cohead_number "Sales Order#",
       cohead_custponumber "Purchase Order#",
       item_number "Part Number",
       item_descrip1 "Part Description",
       CAST(shipitem_qty AS integer) "Item Quantity",
      --  getPacklistItemLotSerial(shiphead.shiphead_id, coitem.coitem_id) AS "LotNumbers"  --this is the duplicating row subquery that I need listed in separate rows without changing other respective columns--
       CASE WHEN EXISTS(  
                 SELECT metric_value FROM metric
                 WHERE metric_name='LotSerialControl' AND metric_value ='t'
            )
            THEN x.ls_number
            ELSE ''
        END AS "LotNumbers"
FROM   cohead
       LEFT JOIN coitem
              ON coitem_cohead_id = cohead_id
       LEFT JOIN shipitem
              ON coitem_id = shipitem_orderitem_id
       LEFT JOIN itemsite
              ON coitem_itemsite_id = itemsite_id
       LEFT JOIN item
              ON itemsite_item_id = item_id
       LEFT JOIN shiphead
              ON shiphead_order_id = cohead_id
       LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT ls_number,
                   shipitem_shiphead_id, -- parameter: pShipheadId 
                   shipitem_orderitem_id -- parameter pOrderItemId
              FROM invdetail, invhist, shipitem, ls
             WHERE 
               -- (shipitem_shiphead_id=pShipheadId)
               -- AND  (shipitem_orderitem_id=pOrderItemId)
               (shipitem_invhist_id=invhist_id)
               AND  (invhist_id=invdetail_invhist_id)
               AND  (invdetail_ls_id=ls_id)
       ) x
       ON ( x.shipitem_shiphead_id = shiphead.shiphead_id
            AND
            x.shipitem_orderitem_id = coitem.coitem_id
       )
WHERE cohead_number = '79464'
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Easy to see what was changed too, it would have taken me a lot longer to figure that out.  Thank you sooooo much and perfect detailed answer.